# Parsing a text file in c++ and storing strings in separate variables

Tags: c++, parsing, vector, text-files

I have a text file that will be something like this.

```
lastname firstname, id
```

I want to go through the text file and add each record into a single vector that has 3 variables: `lastname, firstname, id`

Here is the code I'm using, but for some reason I don't get the output I want.

```
int Student::readStudents(vector<Student> &term){
  ifstream infile("spring2011.txt"); 
  if ( !infile ) {
    cout << "Error attempting to open file ... "
         << "(Perhaps it dosen't exist yet?)" << endl;
    return -1;          // report error condition ...
  }


  term.clear(); // empty the student vector
  string lname,fname, id;
  int j;
  while(infile){
    getline( infile, lname, ' ');
    getline(infile,fname, ',');
    getline(infile, id, ' '); 
    term.push_back( Student(lname, fname, id) ); // construct and add new Student
    j++;
 }
  infile.close();
  return j; //count of records
}
```

This is the function I'm using to display the records in the vector.

```
void Student::showStudents(vector<Student> &term){  
 for( size_t i=0; i< term.size(); ++i ){  
        cout << i+1 << ".\n"  
             << "Name   : " << term[i].getLastName()<<", "<<     term[i].getFirstName()<< endl   
             << "Student Number : " << term[i].getId() << endl;   
    }  
}
```

Comment: Indent code by four spaces. **Don't** past with tabs.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Is there nothing stored in the vector? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: there is nothing stored in the vector, i get a text file with names of students such as Bob Marley, 011.... I want to go through the text file and add Bob to fname, marely to lname and 011 to id... and push it into the vector.... After i want to be able to access the vector and print it so it prints like this:

Comment: You should try to insert some couts so we can see what you actually read and write.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are actually constructing an `ifstream` object but not opening the file to perform input operations on it. You are missing the second parameter of the `ifstream` object construction , which actually opens the file as if the call is made to open the file. So try -

```
ifstream infile("spring2011.txt", ifstream::in );
```

or

```
ifstream infile; 
infile.open ("spring2011.txt", ifstream::in);
```

Comment: I did and this is what my output looks like.

Comment: 1.
Name   : Hofnar Tudor 002

Wright Matthew 003
, 
Student Number : 

but i want it to look like:
1.
Name   : Hofnar Tudor 
Student Number : 002
2.Name: Wright Matthew

Comment: Copy how the contents of your text file **spring2011.txt** exactly looks like in the question.

Comment: but they are below each other, that is the two students are on 2 different lines

Comment: @Angad Soni- Is this a typo that one of `getline(infile,fname, ',');` has `,` as the delimeter. Shouldn't it be a space character?

Comment: @Angad Soni - Also shouldn't the last `getline(infile, id, ' ');` be `getline(infile,id);` because `\n` is considered in this case by default.

Comment: yes it should, but for some reason i don't get the results to show up the way i want them to...